# Howto get books from authors using XSLT 1.0 templates

Tags: xslt

I have question about XSLT1.0. The task is to write out in HTML all books written by given authors only by using XSL templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <books>
        <book author="herbert">
            <name>Dune</name>
        </book>
        <book author="herbert">
            <name>Chapterhouse: Dune</name>
        </book>
        <book author="pullman">
            <name>Lyras's Oxford</name>
        </book>
        <book author="pratchett">
            <name>I Shall Wear Midnight</name>
        </book>
        <book author="pratchett">
            <name>Going Postal</name>
        </book>
        <author id="pratchett"><name>Terry Pratchett</name></author>
        <author id="herbert"><name>Frank Herbert</name></author>
        <author id="pullman"><name>Philip Pullman</name></author>
    </books>
```

So far I have this solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head/>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//author"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="author">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[@id=@author]"/>
                --previous XPath does not work properly, it should choose only those books that are written by the given author (that this template matches)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is a problem though, explained in the comment.

---

Thank you Martin and Marzipan - it works now. There is one more thing. What if I wanted to have the book titles for each authors separated by commas? I propose this solution, but is there more elegant way to achieve this?

...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[current()/@id=@author][not(position()=last())]" mode="notLast"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[current()/@id=@author][last()]"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="book">
            <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="book" mode="notLast">
            <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
            <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just realized my question has been already answered by Marzipan. Quesion is solved then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `<xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[current()/@id=@author]"/>` or better yet a key (as a child of the xsl:stylesheet element):

```
<xsl:key name="book-by-author" match="books/book" use="@author"/>
```

and then `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('book-by-author', @id)"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[@id=@author]"/>
```

Understand that, when you enter a predicate, the context changes to the nodes matched by the preceding XPath selector. The context is no longer the node matched by the template it is within.

To get round this, commit the author's ID to a variable, then use that inside your predicate instead.

```
<xsl:variable name='author_id' select='@id' />
...
[@author=$author_id]
```

[EDIT - or, as Martin pointed out in his answer, use `current()` to force the context]

You can run it here:

http://www.xmlplayground.com/10FRcA